# How to handle a different layout for a bootstrap form

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

I have 13 fields of a form to write into a template.
Some of them have to be on the same "row", like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6"> {{ my field #1 }} </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6"> {{ my field #2 }} </div>
</div>
```

and some of them have to be on different rows with `col-lg` set to `12` like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12"> {{ my field #3 }} </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12"> {{ my field #4 }} </div>
</div>
```

... and sometimes my client wants to see 4 fields on the same row:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3"> {{ my field #5 }} </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3> {{ my field #6 }} </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3"> {{ my field #7 }} </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3"> {{ my field #8 }} </div>
</div>
```

When you write a form in Django template, you usually do a loop like this:

```
{% for field in form_basique.visible_fields %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group {% if field.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
        {% if field.label %}
        <label>{{ field.label }}</label>
        <label for="{{ field.auto_id }}" class="sr-only">{{ field.label }}            </label>
        {% endif %}
        {{ field }}
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

My question is: how would you do a for loop in the template and deal with different layouts like the ones I want?

Comment: You could the slicing template tag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/, and use a different `for` loop for each slice

Comment: Yes, but how to indicate the template that this field should be on the same row than another field?

Comment: What's the your jinja version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using the Django way of handling conditional extends (this method requires the use of a boolean variable and a yesno filter).
The filter checks if the given value is truthy and returns the yes parameter if it is, no otherwise.

```
 env.addFilter('yesno', function(str, yes, no) {
  return str ? yes : no;
});
env.render('index.html', {
  isAjaxRequest: true
});
// or simpler using Express, isAjax will be automatically passed as context to Nunjucks.
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.isAjax = req.get('X-PJAX') ? true : false;
  next();
  // later, app.render('index.html');
});
```

And in the template we use the variable lo extend the right template:

```
{% extends isAjaxRequest|yesno('ajax.html', 'layout.html') %}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I dont understand. I'm talking about a very classical webpage, no ajax, no javascript...

Comment: No, This example show the Ajax, Yet the technique solve your problem.  This way you can choose between html extend